# Animate Title to Bottom then Animate Back to Top and Disappear

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a portfolio and when you hover over a work example the title appears at the top and then animates to the bottom of that particular work example. On mouseOut I would like the title to animate back to the top and then disappear. My problem with the code below is that as soon as I mouseOut the title disappears without showing the animation back to the top. Do I need to chain this somehow?

```
$('div.recentWork').hover(
function(){
$(this).find('.showTitle').animate({marginTop: "150px"});
$(this).find('.showTitle').css({display: "block", background: "black"});
},
function(){
$(this).find('.showTitle').animate({marginTop: "0px"});
$(this).find('.showTitle').css({display: "none"});
}
);
```

Answer (score 1):

set a timeout on

```
$(this).find('.showTitle').css({display: "none"});
```

using a

```
window.setTimeOut()
```

like so:

```
var foo = window.setTimeOut((function(){$(this).find('.showTitle').css({display: "none"});}),1000)
```

Comment: Great thank you.. does this get placed inside the handlerOut function?

Comment: inside the mouseout what this does is tells the code to wait 1000 ms before executing

Comment: I tried it like this but no luck... 
function(){   $(this).find('.showTitle').animate({marginTop: "0px"});
var foo = window.setTimeOut((function(){$(this).find('.showTitle').css({display: "none"});}),1000);}

Comment: @cpcdev google "javascript timeout", im not sure exactly what to use in your case, but the idea should help.

Comment: You should just use the `complete` callback instead.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the display:none is called right after the animate action is called, without waiting for it to finish.

You have to put the second action in a callback of your first, so it's fired only as soon as the animate is done.

I haven't tested the code but it should be something like that:

```
$('div.recentWork').hover(function(){
  $(this).find('.showTitle').animate({marginTop: "150px"});
  $(this).find('.showTitle').css({display: "block", background: "black"});
}, function() {
  $(this).find('.showTitle').animate({
    marginTop: "0px"
  }, 500, function() {
    $(this).find('.showTitle').css({display: "none"});
  });
});
```

edit: just tested my code and it works :)

Comment: Thanks for your response.. when I use this code though it's still not hiding

Comment: no errors.. everything works as it should except for the title disappearing at the end

Answer (score 0):

Your `display: 'none'` is happening before you animation ends. Try something like:

```
$('div.recentWork').hover(
  function(){
    $(this).find('.showTitle').animate({marginTop: '150px'}, 'slow', function(){
      $(this).find('.showTitle').css({display: 'block', background: 'black'});
    });
  },
  function(){
    $(this).find('.showTitle').animate({marginTop: '0px'}, 'slow', function(){
      $(this).find('.showTitle').css({display: 'none'});
    });
  }
);
```